# git remote branch bringing to local with different ssh machine

Tags: git

there are 2 machines, which i use.

i have cloned one git repository of application which i work on.

on machine A i have cloned this repo, have worked on various features on different branches which i created and committed and pushed remotely.

So remotely i have 3 branches now, one is the master, rest 2 branch1, branch2 of my features.

on machine 2 i have cloned the repository 'master' branch.

my question is how i get the branch1, branch2 on my machine 2 .

so that i can commit stuff from machine 2 too.

thanks in advance.

(sorry for bad english)

Comment: You could use bitbucket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can

```
git fetch --all
git branch -r # will list all remote branches
git checkout <branch> # notice that the branch name should not have leading 'origin', it is the *local* branch name
```

git will create local branch tracking the remote branch with same name.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-do-i-clone-all-remote-branches-with-git).

Comment: thanks for the reply. it worked. so if i commit and push my changes from machine 2 , i will have to do a 'git pull branch_name_i_commited_in'. am i right ?

Comment: @jospratik Yes, you are right. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357122/git-pull-vs-git-fetch-git-rebase), it introduced a better practice of using `git pull` and `git pull --rebase` selectively.