# How to use `git merge` to achieve same result as `git pull`?

Tags: git

[What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

The question above's top answer says

> "In the simplest terms, git pull does a git fetch followed by git
>   merge or git rebase."

I understand that `git fetch && git rebase` is literally `git pull`.

But how to use `git fetch` and `git merge` to achieve the same result?

Here is my experiment:

```
git fetch && git rebase # correctly replays remote commits in working copy

git fetch && git merge upstream/master # error
merge: upstream/master - not something we can merge
```

I would expect `git merge` to be able to correctly replay remote commits in the current working copy - which is what `git pull` does.

Comment: Which result are you talking about? It already produces the same end result (because `git pull` is nothing more than a shell script calling fetch, then merge – you can even look at its source code)

Comment: As stated in your quote, basically the result is the same; anyway it looks like you have no clear idea about the differences between rebase and merge

Comment: It simply does not work. `git fetch && git rebase` correctly replays upstream changes in my working copy, `git fetch && git merge` does not do anything and gives an error "not something we can merge".

Comment: @HowardGuo you cannot simply type `git merge`, you need to specify which branchs do you want to merge

Comment: @iberbeu I did `git merge upstream/master`. without upstream, git merge complains other error.

Comment: `git merge` does never replay your local commits. It either creates a new merge commit or fast-forwards your current branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `git fetch + git merge` like `git fetch; git merge origin/master` to achive same behaviour as default behaviour of `git pull`. But default behaviour can be changed to use rebase.

More about differences between merge and rebase are here: [git pull VS git fetch git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357122/git-pull-vs-git-fetch-git-rebase)

Comment: `git pull` does not change its behavior depending on whether you have changes or not. It will use merge, unless you call it as `git pull --rebase`.

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch
```

this command wil download the status of the remote repository and its branches but will do nothing with your local copy

```
git merge branch_to_merge
```

this command will merge the branch_to_merge in the branch you currently are. You cannot just type git merge without parameters because git will reply with: `fatal: No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set`

```
git rebase
```

This command will let you rewrite the history of your branch and put it over the specified commit

Comment: Then how to git merge "remote repository status" (master branch) with the master branch working copy?

Comment: got to local master `git checkout master` and then merge the status of the remote copy (let say origin) `git merge origin/master`. All this of course after doing `git fetch origin`