# Couldn't merge origin/master: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, android-studio, github, merge

I make some changes and commits to my project locally but didn't push them, then  I change files in GitHub by adding new file and commit.

when I try to push my local commits android studio suggested to merge but when I try to merge it give me that error and whatever I do keep refusing to merge and show me that message.

[image]

and when I click merge shows me.

Error message:

[image]

My log:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the error message? What is the state of your working directory and your origin/master branch? You can use `git log` to fetch this information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore error on git pull about my local changes would be overwritten by merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/how-to-ignore-error-on-git-pull-about-my-local-changes-would-be-overwritten-by-m)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve git saying "Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745045/how-do-i-resolve-git-saying-commit-your-changes-or-stash-them-before-you-can-me)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your local changes will need to be stashed away while you perform the merge. To do that, git provides `git stash` to save your uncommitted changes to a temporary location, and `git stash pop` to apply them back to your local code.

This should work:

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
```

Here's a good website to learn more about git: http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/13/smartly-save-stashes.html

But after looking at your screenshot, a merge doesn't seem like the best option for you. Instead a rebase would make more sense.

```
git stash
git pull --rebase origin master
git stash pop
```

Here are some resources to understand the difference between a merge and a rebase:

- http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/31/intro-to-rebase.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357174/2651774

Comment: thanks a lot man, the rebase method worked very well, however I didn't fully understand what happened but I will spend more time on learning git.

Comment: and Please if you can explain why did this problem occurs in the first place, so I didn't fall in it again.

Comment: The problem occurred in the first place because you had changes locally that hadn't yet been committed. You can see those by running `git status`.

Comment: Both merges and rebases can't be run if there are uncommitted changes locally.

Comment: @seanlinsley This answer is one of the greatest answers on this site. Thanks a lot!