# Git Pull vs Git Rebase

Tags: git

I'm a noob in Git, and trying to learn the difference between `git pull` vs `git rebase`. Can someone provide an example when to use which option since I feel that both serve the same purpose.

Comment: Yes I did. The difference between pull and rebase is that pull does a merge. So the answer to your question is at the link i pasted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between 'git merge' and 'git rebase'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git pull VS git fetch Vs git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357122/git-pull-vs-git-fetch-vs-git-rebase)

Answer (score 266):

`git pull` and `git rebase` are not interchangeable, but they are closely connected.

`git pull` fetches the latest changes of the current branch from a remote and applies those changes to your local copy of the branch. Generally this is done by merging, i.e. the local changes are merged into the remote changes. So `git pull` is similar to `git fetch & git merge`.

Rebasing is an alternative to merging. Instead of creating a new commit that combines the two branches, it moves the commits of one of the branches on top of the other.

You can pull using rebase instead of merge (`git pull --rebase`). The local changes you made will be rebased on top of the remote changes, instead of being merged with the remote changes.

Atlassian has some excellent [documentation on merging vs. rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/workflow-walkthrough).

Comment: So what's actual diffrence between putting feature on top of master 
and merging feature with master , in the end both are mixed aren't they ?

Comment: The content of the resulting commit is indeed indistinguishable. However, the commit tree looks a bit different. The reason I prefer rebasing over merging is that if you have conflicts, you resolve them commit-wise instead of all during the single merge commit. Also, is results in a cleaner more linear commit tree, which makes it easier to walk through.

Comment: When you will check the commit history, if you have used Git Pull, it will show you an extra merge commit, while in git rebase, that wont be there. Git Rebase is a cleaner approach from the context of git history.

Comment: So the only different is history related only...? if I wont these merged changes to be in a separate commit on "rewrite/recommit" the commits

Answer (score 91):

> git-pull - Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch
>   [GIT PULL](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Basically you are pulling remote branch to your local, example:

```
git pull origin master
```

Will pull master branch into your local repository

> git-rebase - Forward-port local commits to the updated upstream head
>   [GIT REBASE](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

This one is putting your local changes on top of changes done remotely by other users.
For example:

- You have committed some changes on your local branch for example called `SOME-FEATURE`
- Your friend in the meantime was working on other features and he merged his branch into master

Now you want to see his and your changes on your local branch.
So then you checkout `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
```

then you can pull:

```
git pull origin master
```

and then you go to your branch:

```
git checkout SOME-FEATURE
```

and you can do rebase `master` to get lastest changes from it and put your branch commits on top:

```
git rebase master
```

I hope now it's a bit more clear for you.

Comment: You do not need to checkout master. Stay on your branch and do: `git fetch` then `git rebase origin/master`.

Comment: By checking out the local master and then pulling origin master will update your local master also. This is one of the best practice should be used

Comment: so what diffrence if we merging master instead of rebase

Comment: @OmarEssamEl-Din "merge" always creates new commit. So you will see one extra merge commit in git commit history. While rebase doesn't create any new commit.

Comment: Best answer so far! I just followed this answer and my butt got saved

Answer (score 59):

In a nutshell :

#### Git Merge:

Merges your local changes and remote changes, and that will create another commit history record

#### Git Rebase:

Put your changes above all new remote changes, and rewrite commit history, so your commit history will be much cleaner than git merge. Rebase is a destructive operation. That means, if you do not apply it correctly, you could lose committed work and/or break the consistency of other developer's repositories.