# Rebase git feature branch

Tags: git, rebase, pull

I am trying to rebase my feature branch.

I created feature branch name "feature/task1" from 'develop'. After that made changes in feature branch and commit -> push branch to remote and created pull request.(But, work still in progress).

Now, other person made some changes to 'develop' branch. I want that changes to local "feature/task1" branch.

I tried "**git pull --rebase**" but it shows.

> error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.

So, i tried following as i don't want to discard some local changes also don't want to commit.

1.) `git stash`
2.) `git pull --rebase`
3.) `git stash pop`

But, still i can't see those latest changes to my feature branch.

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517464/error-cannot-pull-with-rebase-you-have-unstaged-changes) but, not helped much. (If i checkout develop branch i can see latest changes but, not in my feature branch).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Pull vs Git Rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148602/git-pull-vs-git-rebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you said you created feature/task1 from develop, you mean *local* develop? If that's the case, pull won't work, no matter what you do, because you will have to first pull into *local* develop so that you can pull into your feature branch. You could set the upstream branch to be the *remote* develop and then it should work

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/develop #adjust name of remote, if it's not origin
git pull -r
```

or you could do it manually

```
git fetch --all
git rebase origin/develop
```