# Git pull vs git pull --rebase

Tags: git, branch

In reference to this well-written answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675513/1139436

*If you actually feel the need for something to be a branch for whatever reason...*

What is being referred to here, by "branch"? In our workflow, we branch off the master to make bugfixes, new features, etc, then, push those changes to gerrit for review, which, once approved, (I assume, I did not set it up) merges them into master.  Are these the branches that were being referred to, or is the comment referring to something larger (projects diverging, etc)?

Back to our workflow... Once the changes are submitted, we `git checkout master`, `git pull`* and `git branch -D bugfix_branch`.  I marked pull with a * since, that has often led to merge commits in my local master.  I started using `git pull --rebase` and no longer see those merge commits, but I admit, I don't understand at all what is happening under the hood.

Why am I seeing merge commits and, do I want them? Am I better to `--rebase` and avoid them? Noone seems to have an answer either way, so long as it "just works".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357122/git-pull-vs-git-fetch-git-rebase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, the decisions about whether to use a merge oriented work-flow, a rebase oriented work-flow, or some hybrid—i.e., use both, choosing which one based on judgment—is a matter of opinion and, well, judgement.<sup>1</sup>  There are good arguments on both sides.  Here are two outside opinion pages, [one by Ken Sheedlo in favor of rebase](http://kensheedlo.com/essays/why-you-should-use-a-rebase-workflow/) and [one that lists arguments on both sides](https://dev.to/neshaz/git-merge-vs-git-rebase-5134), plus the [Atlassian tutorial page](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing) on merging vs rebasing.

The thing to realize about rebase is that it *copies* (some) commits.  If you understand the Git model of representing commits as a *graph*,<sup>2</sup> the example in Ken Sheedlo's pro-rebase argument shows you exactly what this means: the original commits `B` and `C` in:

```
  B--C   <-- feat
 /
A--D--E   <-- master
```

are figuratively abandoned to the wolves, in favor of the shiny new replacements `B'` and `C'`:

```
  B--C   [abandoned]
 /
A--D--E   <-- master
       \
        B'-C'  <-- feat
```

Having replaced the dull icky old `B-C` chain with the shiny new `B'-C'` chain of commits, the new feature branch can now be seamlessly incorporated into `master`, with or without a merge commit.  Using the merge commit—running `git merge --no-ff feat` while on `master`—gives you this graph:

```
A--D--E------F   <-- master
       \    /
        B'-C'  <-- feat
```

which helps a historian come along in the future (once the name `feat` is erased, which is safe since `F` remembers `C'` as well as `E`) and see that the commit *pair*, `B'-C'`, is what implemented the feature.  Whether this has value, vs the simpler-looking:

```
A--D--E--B'-C'  <-- master
```

is a separate question.  But the fact that the *true* original commits were `B--C` is lost either way, due to the rebase.  If *that* fact is important for some reason, then you did lose something by rebasing.

That, in its nutshell, is the anti-rebase argument: *you might lose some important bit of history.*  The pro-rebase argument is that these bits of history are not merely *unimportant*, they *actively interfere with understanding*.  Much of computer programming is about abstraction, and abstraction is the art of *removing unnecessary detail*.<sup>3</sup>  This gives you a good "big picture" view.  Once you understand where you are now and where you want to go, *then* you can plot out the gritty details of how you got here and how you can get there.  If you're lost in the weeds of details and have no idea where you are and where you are going, you will at most get lucky with some sort of Brownian motion.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is also true about whether to spell judgment with the extra "e": http://grammarist.com/spelling/judgment-judgement/, https://www.dictionary.com/e/judgement-vs-judgment/

<sup>2</sup>If you *don't*, work through the pages at [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

<sup>3</sup>This is true of mathematics as well.  Graph theory itself arose from *removing unnecessary detail:* Euler's realization that all that mattered were the bridges-and-land-masses.  (See link in footnote 2.)